# Appium with C# and visual studio not working on iOS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, appium, appium-ios

I am trying to install a setup of Appium server on MAC and visual studio on a windows machine. I have installed Node.js version 8.9.4, and npm 5.6.0, Appium server version is 1.4.8 onto MAC, Xcode Version 9.0.1 (9A1004) and trying to launch my .app file. I am getting an error as:

> An exception of type eOpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverExceptionf occurred
>   in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException:
>   Unable to connect to the remote server >
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The requested address is not valid
>   in its context 0.0.0.0:4723
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress)
>
> at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean
>   connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress&
>   address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Exception& exception)
>
> \ End of inner exception stack trace \
>
> at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Service.AppiumCommandExecutor.Execute(Command
>   commandToExecute)
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters).

Please help me solve this issue and launch the app.
I had one more doubt that how do we get the Uri address for the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
Unable to connect to the remote server > System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The requested address is not valid in its context 0.0.0.0:4723
```

You're trying to connect to local appium server(0.0.0.0:4723) but you mention it at the beginning that your appium server is on mac machine so you need to pass it IP of that machine when you're creating session for a test run.